# textbox change event - jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have a textbox control, the script is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" EnableTheming="false" CssClass="calender" 
                        runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

in the calender control if I select a particular date I need to get the records from the database on that particular date, so I tried putting textbox change event as

```
$(function () {
    $('#txtDate').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/DataService.asmx/fetchAbsentees",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'date' : '" + $("#txtDate").val() + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Successfully reached.");
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert("ERROR:" + error.toString() + " " + status + " " + req.responseText);
            }
        });
    }).triggerHandler('change');
});
```

the webservice is getting fired from here fine, but its firing whenever I run the application, I want it to be fired only when I change the date in the textbox......can anyone help me here.

note: am using master page.

Comment: @Diodeus That's not very constructive :P

Comment: Why do you have .triggerHandler('change') ? That will just immediately trigger the change event.

Comment: remove your `triggerHandler`!!

Comment: thanks Diodeus,chris Dowdeswell and silly, I just removed the triggerHandler and its working fine now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the following part:

```
.triggerHandler('change');
```

this causes the event to fire immediately.

Your final code should look like the following:

```
$(function () {

    $('#txtDate').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/DataService.asmx/fetchAbsentees",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'date' : '" + $("#txtDate").val() + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Successfully reached.");
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert("ERROR:" + error.toString() + " " + status + " " + req.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks musefan for ur solution, actually I tried with the change event first, it was not working at that time and for that only I tried triggerHandler, its working fine after removing the triggerHandler.......I think I only changed something....thanks alot